# Writing in same row in Gujarati in python using CSV writer

Tags: python, csv, encoding

My code:

```
import csv

# Create a list of Gujarati strings
strings = [['હેલો, વર્લ્ડ!', 'સુપ્રભાત', 'મારા નામ હેઠળ છે']]

# Open the CSV file in 'w' mode
with open('Gujarati.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-16',newline='') as f:
    # Create a CSV writer
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # Write the strings to the CSV file

    writer.writerows(strings)
```

I am trying to write each heading as a different column, but I don't know why it is getting in the same column. I want it to be in separate columns. I don't know what else to write but feel free to ask me anything anytime.

I appreciate any help you can provide[image]

Comment: Not reproducible.

Comment: @OlvinRoght why do you say that? It's obviously reproducible

Comment: @jprebys, I've executed same code and everything was writtern in separate columns

Comment: I'm assuming you mean separate columns? And if you know how `writerows` works, you will know that the post is correct

Comment: @jprebys, yes, I've meant separate columns. [Code](https://tio.run/##PY6/CsIwEIf3PEWcmooUwcXFB3BycCwO/qkaxKakUXF0chCfwEXBQa4oogi6@Cz3JvXatC5Hvu/ufrlobaYqbDQjnaZyHiltuFSseA3jJWNarWLe4r7vIHww2SI8MNnVOMIL4Y7JPhdUTxWnxmnojckGAXJ3R7gifBHOtnfLgeyX9i853HiZe0R4EhwInF6PDRZj@lcqr2u0DCftjnDZSksTaNJ0mmdB0FzZKBRdLLLiZhleHAQzUXeZDvqj/64FuxtRvBFVq1yWpj8).

Comment: I mean separate columns because the columns are not getting separated in utf-16 and any other encoding dosen't support Gujarati.@jprebys

Comment: You just showed that it read back into a nested list of strings, which was the original problem

Comment: I didn't understood @jprebys, can you code it?

Comment: I got `"હેલો, વર્લ્ડ!",સુપ્રભાત,મારા નામ હેઠળ છે` (exactly 3 comma-separated columns). Are you sure that your _Excel_ import is configured for comma-separated columns?

Comment: @JosefZ I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: [Import or export text (.txt or .csv) files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba#:~:text=You%20can%20import%20data%20from,to%20import%2C%20and%20click%20Import.) *You can change the separator character that is used in both delimited and .csv text files. This may be necessary to make sure that the import or export operation works the way that you want it to.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba#:~:text=You%20can%20import%20data%20from,to%20import%2C%20and%20click%20Import](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba#:%7E:text=You%20can%20import%20data%20from,to%20import%2C%20and%20click%20Import).

Import or export text (.txt or .csv) files You can change the separator character used in both delimited and .csv text files. This may be necessary to ensure that the import or export operation works the way you want it to.